# How to send soap messages asynchronously from java

Tags: java, soap, asynchronous, jms, activemq-classic

The business situation is that we want our application to notify a third party every once in a while on the occurrence of a certain event in our application, sending them some data. We could say that we are the publisher and the third party is a subscriber.

If they have a soap service expecting soap messages as the notification, what is a best practice way of communicating with their service? I'd like for it to be asynchronous, because I don't want our app to slow down to notify them. I also need it to be guaranteed delivery, retrying if their service is down.

From reading around, it looks like I could use activeMQ - but wouldn't that require them to have a JMS destination that can connect to MQ on their end?

What I'd ideally like is some kind of transparent message broker that will send a soap request on my behalf, retrying until it gets a successful response. Does something like that exists, and is that a sensible architectural choice for this scenario?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP is a request/response protocol.  While the underlying transports can be asynchronous, this is typically hidden from the client to whom it appears to be synchronous.

The best way to handle these sort of notifications is purely over JMS/MQ.  This does however assume you have control over or the desire to change the client, so that it can consume messages from a queue.

If this is not the case then a queue is still the way to go.

Notifications should be posted to a queue.  A process or thread needs to consume notifications from that queue and make the SOAP call with the appropriate retry logic that re-queues the notification if that call fails.  Depending on your requirements this could be as simple as an in-memory queue or, if you need the notifications to survive process restarts, an external queue server like ActiveMQ.

Either way the pattern is the same:

- you queue your notification
- a consumer on another thread or in another process consumes the notification and makes the SOAP call
- if the SOAP call fails you re-queue the notification

Comment: Thanks for your reply - that's very useful.. So you consume from your own queue, making the soap calls in a separate thread and requeueing them if they fail.. Great - thank you!